# How does a computer resize an image?

Tags: html, image

Image resizing is nearly universal in any GUI framework. In fact, one of the first things you learn when starting out in web development is how to scale images using CSS or HTML's *img* attributes. But how does this work?

When I tell the computer to scale a 500x500 img to 100x50, or the reverse, how does the computer know which pixels to draw from the original image? Lastly, is it reasonably easy for me to write my own "image transformer" in another programming language without significant drops in performance?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

Comment: The wikipedia article is... less than thrilling when it comes to the actual technique used by modern browsers. Looking at this [link](http://www.entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/browsers/), it seems that several custom algorithms are used, which requires further study.

Comment: Yes, as an author you can even have some control over which algos should be used: [for raster images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) and  [for vector ones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a bit of research, I can conclude that most web browser will use nearest neighbor or linear interpolation for image resizing. I've written a concept nearest neighbor algorithm that successfully resizes images, albeit VERY SLOWLY.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Timers;

namespace Image_Resize
{
    class ImageResizer
    {
        public static Image Resize(Image baseImage, int newHeight, int newWidth)
        {
            var baseBitmap = new Bitmap(baseImage);
            int baseHeight = baseBitmap.Height;
            int baseWidth = baseBitmap.Width;

            //Nearest neighbor interpolation converts pixels in the resized image to pixels closest to the old image. We have a 2x2 image, and want to make it a 9x9.
            //Step 1. Take a 9x9 image and shrink it back to old value. To do this, divide the new width by old width (i.e. 9/2 = 4.5)
            float widthRatio = (float)baseWidth/newWidth;
            float heightRatio = (float)baseHeight/newHeight;

            //Step 2. Perform an integer comparison for each pixel in old I believe. If we have a pixel in the new located at (4,5), then the proportional will be
            //(.8888, 1.11111) which SHOULD GO DOWN to (0,1) coordinates on a 2x2. Seems counter intuitive, but imagining a 2x2 grid, (4.5) is on the left-bottom coordinate
            //so it makes sense the to be on the (0,1) pixel.


            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            int oldX = 0; int oldY = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < newWidth; i++)
            {
                oldX = (int)(i*widthRatio);
                for (int j = 0; j < newHeight; j++)
                {
                    oldY = (int)(j*heightRatio);
                    Color newColor = baseBitmap.GetPixel(oldX,oldY);
                    resized.SetPixel(i,j, newColor);
                }

            }

            //This works, but is 100x slower than standard library methods due to GetPixel() and SetPixel() methods. The average time to set a 1920x1080 image is a second.
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Resizing the image took " + watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + "ms.");
            return resized;

        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\kpsin\Pictures\codeimage.jpg");
            img = ImageResizer.Resize(img, 1000, 1500);
            img.Save(@"C:\Users\kpsin\Pictures\codeimage1.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

I do hope that someone else can come along and provide either a) a faster algorithm for nearest neighbor because I'm overlooking something silly, or b) another way that image scalers work that I'm not aware of. Otherwise, question... answered?